# CMake 3.11 falha ao compilar REGEX

Tags: compilação

Estou tentando configurar uma biblioteca com o CMake 3.11 e estou obtendo um erro de compilação de uma string REGEX, o projeto pede o FLEX 2.5 com a função `find_package`:

```
find_package(FLEX 2.5 REQUIRED)
```

Essa chamada utiliza o módulo *FindFLEX.cmake*, na linha 137 desse módulo tem a instrução que gera o erro:

```
string(REGEX REPLACE "^.*${FLEX_EXE_NAME_WE}(${FLEX_EXE_EXT})?\"? (version )?([0-9]+[^ ]*)( .*)?$" "\\3"
```

O erro é:

> CMake Error at D:/CMake/share/cmake-3.1/Modules/FindFLEX.cmake:137 (string):
>       string sub-command REGEX, mode REPLACE failed to compile regex
>       "^.*flex++(.exe)?"? (version )?([0-9]+[^ ]*)( .*)?$".
>       Call Stack (most recent call first):
>
> CMakeLists.txt:58 (find_package)

O diretório do FLEX 2.5 já foi configurado.

Agradeço a atenção de todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltou fechar o parêntese no final da linha.

```all
string(REGEX REPLACE "^.*${FLEX_EXE_NAME_WE}(${FLEX_EXE_EXT})?\"? 
(version )?([0-9]+[^ ]*)( .*)?$" "\\3")
```

No [código](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindFLEX.cmake#L137) do FindFLEX.cmake essa linha na verdade está assim:

```all
string(REGEX REPLACE "^.*${FLEX_EXE_NAME_WE}(${FLEX_EXE_EXT})?\"? 
(version )?([0-9]+[^ ]*)( .*)?$" "\\3" FLEX_VERSION "${FLEX_version_output}")
```

Comment: o executável do FLEX que eu estava utilizando era o flex++.exe, quando eu mudei para flex.exe funcionou, mas também não faz diferença, já mudei a API e já consegui compilar, agradeço por sua atenção.